# Create ArrayList from JFileChooser instead of hard coded option

Tags: java, swing, csv, jfilechooser

I currently access my .csv file via hardcoded ArrayList.  I want to be able to select the file, instead of it being hard coded like it is currently.

I just added the JFileChooser.  I cannot get get my rowData to read line by line of the file selected through JOptionPane.  How do I do this?

```
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV Files", "csv");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        System.out.println("You chose to open file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
    }
```

my Original Code started here (without the commented line), and it works.  I just don't want it hard coded in.

```
    ArrayList<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileConnections excelConn = new FileConnections();
    //rowData = excelConn.read(chooser);
    rowData = excelConn.read(new File("11738 IPACC INFINITY Unconfirmed OIVS Responses.csv"));
```

Comment: What is your issue?  It seems like half of your question is probably irrelevant.  I'm not sure if it's a question about reading a CSV file or a question about using JFileChooser.

Comment: You just need to merge the two, still read into an ArrayList but replace the hardcoded file with `chooser.getSelectedFile()`

Comment: @tieTYT - My issue is I get error when I uncomment out //rowData = excelConn.read(chooser).  I want to be able to select the file, then read from it.  Right now, it just reads from what I've hardcoded.  The filename will change multiple times, that is why I need the file chooser.

Comment: From your code I assume you pass a `File` to the method `excelConn.read()`. Therefore pass `chooser.getSelectedFile()` rather than `chooser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested btw!):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV Files", "csv");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
    System.out.println("You chose to open file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
    ArrayList<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileConnections excelConn = new FileConnections();
    rowData = excelConn.read(chooser.getSelectedFile());
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV Files", "csv"));
if(chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("You chose to open file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
    ArrayList<String> rowData = new FileConnections().read(chooser.getSelectedFile());
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it appears to be working.  Having a TNS issue, but it worked until it got to the database I'm comparing it to.  I'll accept when I get the database working.  THANK YOU!